# Set automation property of a button in CS file

Tags: c#, button, uwp

I have a UWP app which has a button implemented in .cs file. Button was created using this code in CS file,

```
var button = new Button();
button.Background = new SolidColorBrush();
button.Opacity = 1.0;
button.Name = "Test Button";
```

But when I tried Narrator it does not Say the complete button name. Just say, "Button". Is there any way to change the name properties some way so that Narrator tells it properly?

I have tried **"button.Name"** and **"button.Content"** but both does not work. And Narrator does not say complete name of the button.

Comment: The Name property of a UWP control is not used for accessibility purposes. Instead, you should use the AutomationProperties.Name property, which is specifically designed for screen readers like Narrator. You could add this line to your code: `AutomationProperties.SetName(button, "Test Button");`Hope this solves it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a summary based on @MySpaceDotNet's comment.

Please set the `AutomationProperties.Name property` of the control for accessibility purposes. This property is designed for screen readers like Narrator.

You could add the following code:

```
AutomationProperties.SetName(button, "Test Button");
```